# Pandas merge on column 2 if column 1 did not produce a match

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge

So I have two tables I'd like to merge. However, the column in the second table has references to two columns of the first table, e.g.:

Table 1 python:

```
table1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Key1': ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'],
    'Key2': ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Oranges'],
    'Text': ['Hello', 'World', '!'],
    'Values': [5, 8, 12],
    })
```

Table 1:

```
╔════════╦═════════╦═══════╦════════╗
║  Key1  ║  Key2   ║ Text  ║ Values ║
╠════════╬═════════╬═══════╬════════╣
║ Value1 ║ Apples  ║ Hello ║      5 ║
║ Value2 ║ Pears   ║ World ║      8 ║
║ Value3 ║ Oranges ║ !     ║     12 ║
╚════════╩═════════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

Table 2 python:

```
table2 = pd.DataFrame({'Key1_Key2': ['Value2', 'Apples', 'Oranges'],
                          'Value_to_Extract': ['Value 123', 'Value 88',
                          'Value 99']})
```

Table 2:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════════╗
║ Key1_Key2 ║ Value_to_Extract ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════╣
║ Value2    ║ Value 123        ║
║ Apples    ║ Value 88         ║
║ Oranges   ║ Value 99         ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════════╝
```

I first would like to merge based on `Key1` values, and only if that fails, then on `Key2` values. It should be an exact match, so I am not looking to concatenate Key1 and Key2 and then search for a substring because then if there are values that look alike (e.g. 'Apples' and 'Apple') then it will wreak havoc.

Result should look like this:

```
╔════════╦═════════╦═══════╦════════╦══════════════════╗
║  Key1  ║  Key2   ║ Text  ║ Values ║ Value_To_Extract ║
╠════════╬═════════╬═══════╬════════╬══════════════════╣
║ Value1 ║ Apples  ║ Hello ║      5 ║ Value 88         ║
║ Value2 ║ Pears   ║ World ║      8 ║ Value 123        ║
║ Value3 ║ Oranges ║ !     ║     12 ║ Value 99         ║
╚════════╩═════════╩═══════╩════════╩══════════════════╝
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: It's pretty obvious I thought from the title, descriptions AND examples + output expectation.. anyway not a reason to downvote as this could provide helpful to others as well

Comment: Reason to downvote is your lack of honest attempt at whatever question you're asking

Comment: Ok.. thanks for your feedback. I will try better next time, and suggest that you try and edit the question to help instead of comment really..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should perform the two [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) independently, then [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) in order of preference to fill the missing values only where the first merge failed:

```
m1 = table1.merge(table2, left_on='Key1', right_on='Key1_Key2', how='left')
m2 = table1.merge(table2, left_on='Key2', right_on='Key1_Key2', how='left')

                    # uncomment to remove merge column
m1.combine_first(m2)#.drop(columns='Key1_Key2')
```

output:

```
     Key1     Key2   Text  Values Key1_Key2 Value_to_Extract
0  Value1   Apples  Hello       5    Apples         Value 88
1  Value2    Pears  World       8    Value2        Value 123
2  Value3  Oranges      !      12   Oranges         Value 99`
```

Comment: Thanks mozway for the answer. However, when I run your script, I still get a NaN for Value2. I just copy pasted your code

Comment: @KMNJB there was a typo in your table2 code (I fixed it in the question to match the text table)

Comment: I thought I commented already, but I had indeed forgotten to update my own script. Thanks a lot, it works!

Comment: @KMNJB you had commented it. Maybe deleted? Or we both dreamt about it ;)